# Combined subsetting in R?

Tags: r, function, subset

I trying to subset 3 `y`s for when `x`s are `-1`, `0`, and `1` in my code below. But I was hoping to do this all at once using `y[c(x == -1, x == 0, x == 1)]` which apparently does not work (see below).

Any better way to do this subsetting all at once?

```
x = seq(-1, 1, l = 1e4)
y = dcauchy(x, 0, sqrt(2)/2)
y[c(x == -1, x == 0, x == 1)] ## This subsetting format doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this.

```
y[x == -1| x == 0| x == 1]
```

Or this

```
y[x %in% c(-1, 0, 1)]
```

Comment: But these two give two `y`s! We expect 3 `y`s?

Comment: @rnorouzian https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal